# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n+1)} {n!} (z+2)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am having a little difficulty with this. I need to find the radius of convergence of this problem:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n+1)} {n!} (z+2)^n$$

Using the root test I have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac{\ln(n+1)} {n!}}\\ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}} {\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$

Using the sterling formula for the bottom I obtain $(e/n)$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}} {e/n}$$

Now how do I simplify the top so I can get something nice?

Answer (score 1):

Use the squeeze theorem - for every large enough $n$, you have that $\ln(n+1) <= n$ (why?). Therefore:

$$
1 \le \sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}\le\sqrt[n]{n} \rightarrow1
$$

Comment: do you mean the squeese theorem

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. It's called the sandwich theorem in my native language :-).

Comment: sorry i did not know it was called like that  sorry

Comment: No need to apologize, the squeeze theorem is the correct and popular name in English, which is the language most mathematics is done these days.

Answer (score 0):

Well after solving both top and bottom of the expression i have $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{e/n}$$ after using the squeeze theorem for the top and stirling formula for the bottom. taking the limit i have $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{e/n} = 0$$ So that means the radius of convergence  $R= \infty$

Comment: Exactly. Good job.

Comment: Thanks man i appreciate that